# Repairing twisted or distorted chemfig figures

Tags: chemfig

[image]Hello and thanks in advance,

I know these structures can probably be made easily with `?` markers in the chemfig command designating locations to finish a bond; however, I would like to know if it is possible to repair the obvious twisting observed in these figures without adjusting the commands to use `?`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newenvironment{tightcenter}{%
  \setlength{\topsep}{.5ex}
  \begin{center}
    }{%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tightcenter}
    \chemnameinit{}
    \chemname{\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}\chemfig{CH_2(-[6]OH)-CH_2-C(=[1]O)(-[7]OH)}}{\footnotesize ácido \beta-hidroxi-propiônico}
    \qquad\qquad
    \chemname{\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}\chemfig{O*4(-C(=O)-CH_2-H_2C-)}}{\footnotesize \beta-propiolactona}
\end{tightcenter}

\begin{tightcenter}
    \chemnameinit{}
    \chemname{\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}\chemfig{O*4(-C(=O)-CH_2-HC(-CH_2-CH_3)-)}}{\footnotesize \beta-valerolactona}
    \qquad\qquad
    \chemname{\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}\chemfig{O*5(-C(=O)-CH2-CH2-CH(-CH_3)-)}}{\footnotesize \gamma-valerolactona}
    \qquad\qquad
    \chemname{\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}\chemfig{CH_2*6(-CH_2-O-C(=O)-CH_2-CH_2-)}}{\footnotesize \delta-valerolactona}
\end{tightcenter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it compilable.

Comment: you mean add the preamble?

Comment: You might want have a look at chemfig's concenpt of *departure* ans *arrival* atoms and how to set them for bonds.

Comment: i have tried this and it returns correctly placed bonds; however, the bonds will overlap the letters making it very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

As [Clemens pointed out in the comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437576/repairing-twisted-or-distorted-chemfig-figures#comment1098233_437576), you have to tell `chemfig` what your departure and arriving atoms are when dealing with groups of atoms and complex geometry.

Besides that, I added math mode for Greek letters and defined bond length globally since you redefine it again and again each time with the same value. I also mildly adjusted appearance of CH2 and H2C groups and code formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\newenvironment{tightcenter}{%
  \setlength{\topsep}{.5ex}
  \begin{center}
    }{%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tightcenter}
    \chemnameinit{}
    \chemname{
        \chemfig{H_2C(-[6,,2]OH)-CH_2-C(=[1]O)(-[7]OH)}
    }{
        \footnotesize ácido $\beta$-hidroxi-propiônico
    }
    \qquad\qquad
    \chemname{
        \chemfig{O*4(-C(=O)-CH_2-H_2C-[,,2])}
    }{
        \footnotesize $\beta$-propiolactona
    }
\end{tightcenter}

\begin{tightcenter}
    \chemnameinit{}
    \chemname{
        \chemfig{O*4(-C(=O)-CH_2-HC(-[,,2,1]CH_2-[,,1,1]CH_3)-[,,2])}
    }{
        \footnotesize $\beta$-valerolactona
    }
    \qquad\qquad
    \chemname{
        \chemfig{O*5(-C(=O)-CH_2-[,,,1]CH_2-HC(-[,,2]H_3C)-[,,2])}
    }{
        \footnotesize $\gamma$-valerolactona
    }
    \qquad\qquad
    \chemname{
        \chemfig{H_2C*6(-CH_2-[,,1]O-C(=O)-[,,,1]CH_2-H_2C-[,,2])}
    }{
        \footnotesize $\delta$-valerolactona
    }
\end{tightcenter}
\end{document}
```

[image]